# java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.io.FilePermission) in unsigned applet

Tags: java, security, applet, local-files

I have a problem with access to local file from unsigned applet. I have read a lot of different resourses (oracle, sun documentation, forums, including stackoverflow) and they all told me, that instead of signing an applet, i can fix security policy.

What am i trying to do is to play .wav file. For sake of simplifying i have put all the files in the same directory:

```
D:\<username>\IdeaProjects\SimpleAppletTest\out\production\SimpleAppletTest
```

in this directory i have next files:

```
01.wav
SimpleApplet.class
SimpleApplet.html
.java.policy
```

The file `.java.policy` that i have created using `policytool` have the following content:

```
/* AUTOMATICALLY GENERATED ON Fri Mar 13 20:44:28 MSK 2015*/
/* DO NOT EDIT */

grant codeBase "file:/D:/<username>/IdeaProjects/-" {
  permission java.io.FilePermission "<<ALL FILES>>", "read";
};
```

and moreover, i have added the next string (the third) to `java.security` which is located at `${java.home}/lib/security/`:

```
policy.url.1=file:${java.home}/lib/security/java.policy
policy.url.2=file:${user.home}/.java.policy
policy.url.3=file:/D:/<username>/IdeaProjects/SimpleAppletTest/out/production/SimpleAppletTest/.java.policy
```

But still when i launch my applet in Internet Explorer (no jokes, please, i just use it to test my applets) i have the next stacktrace in java-console:

```
Java Plug-in 11.31.2.13
Using JRE version 1.8.0_31-b13 Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM
User home directory = D:\<username>
```

...

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-2" java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "D:\<username>\IdeaProjects\SimpleAppletTest\out\production\SimpleAppletTest\01.wav" "read")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.AWTAppletSecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at SimpleApplet$1$1.run(SimpleApplet.java:56)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at SimpleApplet$1.run(SimpleApplet.java:33)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

the code of the applet:

```
 AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction() {
                    public Object run() {
                        File audioSource = new File(
                                "D:\\<username>\\IdeaProjects\\SimpleAppletTest\\out\\production\\SimpleAppletTest",
                                "01.wav");

                        FilePermission perm = new FilePermission(audioSource.getAbsolutePath(), "read");

                        SecurityManager appsm = System.getSecurityManager();
                        appsm.checkPermission(perm);

                        return null;
                    }
                });
```

My JDK and JRE version:

```
java version "1.8.0_20"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_20-b26)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.20-b23, mixed mode)
```

I have Windows 7, actually. And again, i just trying to play .wav file **WITHOUT SIGNING** my applet.

Comment: While I understand that you want to do this, this is VERY, VERY bad idea, because you are providing access to ANY applet to access ANY file on your disk.  This is the reason why this is generally not allowed.  Having said that, make sure that the applet.policy file is located in both your JDK and your JRE.  A better option might be using java's WebStart

Comment: OP--- No one will consider using IE as a joke here,you are free to ask/experiment with all kinds of resources available on this earth. But,please, as explained by @MadProgrammer---this idea of allowing access to codebase all the locations is an extremely bad idea.

Comment: Mr. @MadProgrammer, as i have studied how the `java.policy` syntax works, i am providing access to any applet, which is only located at subdirectories of `file:/D:/<username>/IdeaProjects/` to access any file on my disk. I mean, not ANY applet at all.

What about `applet.policy`, i do not have file named like that at all...

As for your idea about WebStart, i would be happy to use it, but my ordering customer wants exactly applet, unfortunately.

Comment: Mr. @shekharsuman, thanx for your opinion. But despite the fact that it is a terrible idea, it still should work! But it does not, so i am very confused about it and decided to post a question on the stackoverflow.